# What does this strange construction "{} \;" means?

Tags: linux

Why do we use this strange construction `{} \;` in linux terminal for exec command?
For example,

```
find . -type f -name *.jpeg -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for info I found this post in AskUbuntu which I think is family from StackOverflow where an User ask the same as you.

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-a-linux-command)

Hope It is useful.

Comment: I found the answer in that link. Thanks!

Comment: If you are used to develop in Ubuntu/Linux maybe you should sign up in that Forum too. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [man page of find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
> ```
>
> Runs `file' on every file in or below the current directory.  Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from interpretation as shell script  punctuation.  **The semicolon is similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes could have been used in that case also.**

Comment: if you just copy and paste the text of any document/tutorial page, then it should be a comment instead.